# ui-view doesn't render parent style and js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a folder structure like this

```
dashboard (folder)
  -- index.html
route.js
index.html
```

And I my `index.html` I wrap my `ui-view`

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1{color:red}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

Then in `route.js` I have

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html'
        })
}]);
```

But when I go to `localhost:3000/dashboard` I'm seeing a `h1` without color. It's unable to load its parent's 'stuff'. Any idea why?

Comment: From what I have understood, "parent stuff" means the `index.html` that you have given in the question. I don't see any content of its own in the body. Try to include a head tag there before or after `<ui-view>`. And if you are expecting the embedded CSS in parent html to work in the view of your route than I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303777/nested-view-doesnt-work-using-angularjs