# nested view doesn't work using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router, but one strange thing happens, the style which i put in 'parent' doesn't get loaded.

Here's how my folder and files look like

[image]

my route.js look like this

```
.state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "index.html"
            })

            .state("dashboard", {
                url: "/dashboard",
                views:{
                    templateUrl: "layout.html"
                }
            })

            .state("dashboard.index", {
                views:{
                    templateUrl: "dashboard/index.html"
                }
            })
```

I expect layout.html can be the wrap of every module, like I have dashboard module, and module can have many sub-modules but still use the style which located in layout.html.

I've stuck for 6 hours, I need help, I posted my repo [here](https://github.com/eldyvoon/cart-aff).

Comment: Can your provide fiddle and plunker link apart from the repo ??

Comment: You are expecting the CSS rules applied on the parent view to get applied to the child view, am I right?

Comment: @SohanShirodkar correct.

Comment: @SameerK plunker doesn't support nagivate

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"? You mean you can't see the route changes in the URL?

Comment: plunker does support. Here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview

Comment: you didnt specify the url property for the child state